# Запуск консольного приложения из программы и последующее взаимодействие с ним

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Возможно ли запустить с помощью  `System.Diagnostics.Process` консольное приложение, НО чтобы оно запустилось и я вручную мог внести нужные мне данные в запущенное консольное приложение? Если да, то как это можно сделать или где можно об этом получить информацию?

Грубо говоря, мне нужно, чтобы моя программа открывала это консольное приложение таким же образом, как если бы я сам изначально это консольное приложение запускал и работал с ним дальше.

```
Process myProcess = new Process(); 
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "objectmaker\\objectmarker.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; 
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Что Вы уже пробовали сделать?

Comment: @Igor Попытался стандартно запустить с помощью Process, однако приложение открывается и сразу закрывается. Я чувствую, что близко, но чего то нехватает.
`Process myProcess = new Process(); myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "objectmaker\\objectmarker.exe"; myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; myProcess.Start();`

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я понял. Само приложение objectmarker.exe в моем случае без проблем запускается. Это приложение при запуске изначально принимает .bmp картинки из папки rawdata. Выключается оно из за того, что не находит саму папку rawdata (хотя находится в той же директории и если бы я вручную запустил бы objectmarker.exe, то она сработала бы). Это для меня пока загадка, но это уже тема для другого вопроса.

System.Diagnostics.Process работает как надо. Для тех, кто сталкивался с подобным - сначала проверьте "съедает" ли ваше консольное приложение требуемые данные и не отключается ли оно просто из за того, что не может получить требуемые данные.

Comment: По поводу "загадки", почитайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607352/198316). В вашем случае внимание на пункты 3 и 4. А вообще тема относительных путей тут уже много раз обсуждалась в различных вариантах. Ну и освойте любую библиотеку для логирования, чтобы не гадать что произошло, а просто посмотреть =)