# Автозагрузка приложения wpf некорректно работает

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, реестр, автозапуск

есть программа на wpf которая при запуске начинает десериализацию. Я добавил ее в автозагрузку так:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
            try
            {
                key.SetValue("AppName", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                key.Flush();
                key.Close();
            }
            catch { }
```

После перезагрузки пк, программа запускается как в первый раз, до метода с десериализацией не доходит, при запуске мышкой все работает. Создал программу посредника, которая будет запускать основную, но тоже самое. При ручном запуске все работает, при запуске от автозагрузки не доходит до десериализации.

Comment: Нам гадать прикажете? Хорошо... Предположу, что вы проверяете наличие файла и если его нет, то делаете десериализацию или что там, а пути до этого файла у вас привязаны к ["рабочей директории"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607352/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Именно так

Comment: Ну тогда голосую за закрытие как дубликат, а для вас решение по ссылке выше, берите тот вариант, который будет идти от исполняемого файла, а не от рабочей директории и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо помогло