# Не получается прописать относительный путь к файлу .xlsx в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Не может найти относительный путь к таблице. Ошибка внизу
[image: Ошибка]
Абсолютный путь C:\Users\drdra\source\repos\Проект\Проект\bin\debug\Pack.xlsx работает, не могу понять как именно надо прописать относительный.

[image: Код]

Comment: Как думаете, что делает символ `@`? Это прям жирная вам подсказка...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно указать локальный путь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580704/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Собака позволяет экранировать содержимое кавычек, так что намек непонятен, плюс уже пробовал воспользоваться путями @".\Pack.xlsx", "./Pack.xlsx", @"..\..\Pack.xlsx" и прочее. У меня уже эта табличка находится в каждой папке проекта XD

Comment: Допустим вы написали `@"C:\\Dir\\File.txt"`, что у вас будет на выходе? `C:\Dir\File.txt` или `C:\\Dir\\File.txt`? Если второе, то правильный - ли это путь? Правда если писать `@"..\\File.txt"`, то в теории система поймет, но все равно, не лучший вариант. Ну а так, я вам выше дал ссылку, берите там пример с `Path.Combine` и используйте его, ибо, запустив ваше приложение с другим рабочим каталогом, путь будет уже не тот, что вы ожидаете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, чтобы вопрос соответствовал стандартам StackOverflow и не был закрыт по причине того что плохо оформлен, вставьте код текстом, вместо скриншотов.