# Как задать относительный путь для сохранения изображения? C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, save

Нужно сохранить получившееся в picturebox изображение по строго определённому пути (через openFileDialog нельзя)
Часть кода:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null) //если в pictureBox есть изображение
        {
            try
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"codes\Qr", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Невозможно сохранить изображение", "Ошибка",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Относительный путь относительно чего? Что за приложение, WinForms?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607352/373567