# WinPlayer не воспроизводит видео

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С лева ListView, а справа axWindowsMediaPlayer1
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы видео которое находится в папке с приложение, воспроизводилась на другом компьютере.
При нажатии на ListView, есть такой код

```
if (materialListView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = 
            }
```

Соответственно, при нажатии на первый элемент в ListView, должно воспроизводиться видео и т. д.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно прописать, чтобы программа искала путь к этому видео из своей директории. Если я пропишу абсолютный путь, то видео воспроизводиться, а если я начинаю прописывать getdirectoryname и т.д., видео не воспроизводиться.
Вот так выглядит директория
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо того, чтоб создавать новый аккаунт и дублировать удаленный вопрос, отредактировали бы тот, где я все вам объяснил, что и как.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ добрый день, GetCurrentDirectory получает путь из папки запущенного приложения верно?

Comment: Я вам ведь уже все сказал что и как [надо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1293911#comment2281241_1293911), даже дал ссылку на [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607352/220553), где подробно описано как именно стоит прописывать пути к файлам. Но нет, вы это все пропустили мимо ушей, удалили вопрос, а спустя несколько дней создали новый, да еще и под новым аккаунтом. Ну вот скажите, и смысл мне сейчас это по новой все повторять?