# У программы на с# нет прав на доступ к диску

Tags: c#, windows

хочу запустить свою игру из кода с# и в ней есть сохранения json файлы. И когда я вызываю её из кода они не загружаются. Если просто нажать на исполняемый файл, то сохранения загружаются. Видимо у неё нет каких-то прав на доступ к файл(сохранениям) OS - windows 10

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\test\game.exe");`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory)` может отличаться от ожидаемого вами. И уберите .\ в начале пути.

Comment: Еще может надо задать рабочий каталог https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Посмотрел по логам игра решила что она находится рядом с моим исполняемым файлом программки c# который её вызвал из-за этого она не может найти json файлы. Хз почему. Если пускать в ручную, то всё ок.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607352/220553

Comment: Понаблюдайте за Environment.CurrentDirectory при различных сценариях - и будет вам счастье.