# C# не видит файл

Tags: c#

Написал я такой небольшой код:

```
string path = "Новый текстовый документ.txt";
using(StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(path)) 
{

}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Файл "Новый текстовый документ.txt" находится в одной папке с проектом, но C# говорит, что не может найти файл. Но если я пропишу полный путь к файлу, такой ошибки не будет. Как сделать так, чтобы C# видел файл, к которому прописан неполный путь?

Comment: А должен находиться не в папке с проектом, а в текущей рабочей папке

Comment: string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("TestFile.txt"); ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623656/streamreader-to-a-relative-filepath

Comment: В свойствах файла (Properties) задайте Copy to Output Directory значение Copy if newer.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607352/220553

Comment: Да, вот опция копирования должна помочь. Без неё txt файл в bin где будет лежать exe не скопируется.

Comment: В папке debug, release, в зависимости от вашей конфигурации находится папка bin , внутри - папка .Net с номером версии дот нет, туда компилируется все ваши либы и экзешник. Если хотите с путем не заморачиваться, просто, поместите туда txt файл.

Comment: @andreymal, текущая рабочая папка это та, которая находится рядом с файлом .sln?

Comment: Текущая рабочая папка может быть абсолютно любой в зависимости от того, где и как запускается программа

Comment: @KseniyaSinickaya,  а если я создам папку Release и выберу одноименную конфигурацию, программа будет видеть файл, если этот файл будет по-прежнему в папке Debug?

Comment: Вы сейчас задаете бессмысленные вопросы, вам уже все выше сказали что и как надо сделать. Когда вы пишете `"C:/File.txt"` - файл ищется по конкретному пути, но когда вы пишете `"File.txt"` - файл будет искаться в рабочей директории, то есть той директории, из которой был запущен файл, и если она не была переопределена (например создайте ярлык, там будет указание раб. директории, поставите там `C:/`, будет файл искаться в корне диска, а не там, где лежит файл) Чтоб этих проблем не было, я вам дал ссылку выше, указывайте полный путь! Если плевать - ставьте у файла "Всегда копировать" в свойствах

Comment: Решение с папкой бин и дотнет - это элементарное временное решение, когда вам нужно быстро что-то проверить в файле. Любая программа видит файл с именем "файлнейм.тхт" , только если этот файл лежит в той же папке, что и exe. Пока вы не соберете релиз, у вас папка релиз будет пуста. Насколько я помню, там не будет бинарника. Попробуйте поэкспериментировать со сборками и конфигурациями, а то, задавая такие вопросы, вы не сможете это прощупать.

Answer (score 0):

C# не видит файл потому что файла нету в выходной папке проекта.

Чтобы сделать его частью проекта, нужно зайти в свойства файла и выбрать в пункте `Копировать в выходной каталог` одну из двух опций: `Всегда копировать` или `Копировать более позднюю версию`
[image: Открытие свойств проекта]

[image: Выбор свойства копирования в выходной каталог]

Такое же действие можно сделать и без графического интерфейса прописав в свойствах проекта следующее:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Новый текстовый документ.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```